# Chunked Response in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-blob-storage, .net-6.0

I am building a Web API project where I will be fetching PDF files from Azure Blob Storage and send those files as response to API calls.

I have tried using following piece of code

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 

await foreach (var block in azureStorage.DownloadBlobAsync(blobname, cancellationToken)) 
{
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(block, 0, block.Length);
    await Response.Body.FlushAsync(); 
}
    
return new EmptyResult();
```

Where the `DownloadBlobAsync(blobname, cancellationToken)` method fetches the PDF from blob storage in chunks of 4 MB and yields the block.

I am expected the PDF file to start rendering when it starts receiving the first chunk. But when I am running the above logic, the PDF file is rendering only after complete download.

How to achieve rendering when it starts receiving the first chunk?
I have read some blogs which red flags usage of `Response.Body.FlushAsync()`.

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, what are the different ways to send chunked response especially when the return type is a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It is not possible to render the blob data while downloading the PDF blob file using chunks with ASP .net core 6 web API. We can read the PDF blob content using Postman.*

**Code :**

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication42.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BlobController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;
        private readonly string containerName = "<container_name>";

        public BlobController()
        {
            var connectionString = "<connec_string>";
            blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        }
        [HttpGet("{fileName}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadBlob(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
                var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName);

                if (!await blockBlobClient.ExistsAsync())
                {
                    return NotFound($"Blob with name {fileName} not found");
                }

                var properties = await blockBlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
                var contentType = properties.Value.ContentType;

                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"inline; attachment; filename=\"{fileName}\"");
                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType);

                using (var stream = await blockBlobClient.OpenReadAsync())
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[4096]; 

                    while (true)
                    {
                        var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                            break;

                        await Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }

                return new EmptyResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully as shown below.

[image]

I downloaded the PDF blob using chunks, and it's not possible to render the blob data while downloading.

[image]

**Postman :**

I was able to read the PDF blob data using Postman as shown below.

[image]